# Sql server managment studio 2017 dark theme for all ide

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I enable dark theme in ssms but the query resuly window and registered servers window are still white. Is exists any solution to change it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no solution for this.
But maybe you want to give "SQL Operations Studio" (a fork of VS Code, also from MS) a try.
This new tool provides a dark theme as expected.

Look here for a short comparison:
http://blogs.adatis.co.uk/plamenamincheva/post/SQL-Operations-Studio-Vs-(good-old)-SSMS